# How to make my website resolve to https

Tags: dns, https

As of right now if I type: `example.com` I'll get `http://example.com`. I have all the pages set to use HTTPS and after clicking on any link it will start using HTTPS. Is there something I need to change? If I type `google.com`, I'll get `https://google.com`.

Comment: Sorry but you have not provided enough details such as what server software you are using, additionally it could be duplicate as there is already many questions on Pro Webmasters how to redirect from non-ssl to ssl.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up a redirect from `http://mywebsite.com/<whatever>` to `https://mywebsite.com/<whatever>`. It's not a DNS issue at all, and how to do it is entirely dependent on exactly what web server software you're using and how it's configured.

For example, if you use Apache you can create an `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your website:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I know that I forget to from time to time, but it is often best to provide an example or point to an answer that has an example to help the OP. If the question is a duplicate, you can mark the question and a moderator will mark it as a duplicate. Thank You for jumping in and answering this question. I just wanted to give some constructive ideas.

Comment: @closetnoc I edited the question to add an example for Apache (`.htaccess` approach). Hopefully Mike will accept it.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards Excellent! I did not even think of that... need more coffee.

Comment: @closetnoc Here you go http://graytcoffeehouse.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Coffee-Bean.jpg

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards Perfect!! Looks good too!